# proper way to validate django unique_together

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I've searched lots of answers about unique_together, but haven't found anything appropriate. I've got model like this:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True)
    title = models.CharField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "title")
```

And form like this:

```
class SkillForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Skill
    fields = (
        'title',
        ...
        )
```

But now when I try to create new Skill with same user and title I got:
`IntegrityError at /skill/new/ UNIQUE constraint failed: personal_page_platform_skill.user_id, personal_page_platform_skill.title`

I need a proper way to catch this situation without user field in form. I don't want to let users select for whom they are creating Skill.
Problem is not in blank=True of user, because in my view I got user from request. Also  get_or_create method is not for me, I guess.

Here my view, if needed:

```
@login_required
def skill_new(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        form = SkillForm()
        return render(request, '...', {'form': form})
    form = SkillForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
        return render(request, '...', {'form': form})
    skill = form.save(commit=False)
    skill.user = request.user
    skill.save()
    return redirect('...', username=request.user.username)
```

Comment: is `user` a field in SkillForm? If not, the form will not perform the unique_together validation.

Comment: @HåkenLid
No, user field is not in form. So this is one of the problems. I don't want to let users select for whom they creating Skill

Comment: Then can try to override `SkillForm.validate_unique()`. See the duplicate question I linked for details.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks for answer! I'll try.